# Open URL from Windows app with window size

Tags: c#, wpf, browser

In my application, I want to open an url in the browser but want to fix the size of the window.

In Javascript, we can do that easily like below.

I am trying to achieve it in C# windows application.

```html
popUp = window.open('http://www.google.com','Test','scrollbars,width=600,height=430');
```

Could not find any option using

```html
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
```

Basically, I want to open a window with a fixed size.

Should be something to achieve that.

Comment: This is both browser and platform specific, if possible at all. You might be better off using an embedded browser if you need this kind of control.

Comment: @spender Target OS is Windows 7 and 10 and all the computer has Default browser is Google Chrome.
As I don't need any input from the window for that reason want to open an orphan popup.

Comment: If an application ever dares to resize my browser window, I will never ever use that app again. `ShellExecute` your URL and let the system decide for you. Everything else is amateurish to me.

Answer (score 1):

Chromium browser has this ability to process commandline arguments, for example:

**Open window in predefined size:**

```
--window-size   Sets the initial window size. Provided as string in the format "800,600".
```

Start chromium with URL or multiple URLs(multiple tabs)

```
chromium-browser firefox.com [ubuntu.com duckduckgo.com]
```

[Link to chrommium commandline switches.](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#app-shell-host-window-size)

So something like this:

```
  Process runProg = new Process();

  //With path to your chromium browser
  runProg.StartInfo.FileName = "path/to/chromium.exe";
  //Command line arguments for launch
  runProg.StartInfo.Arguments = "--window-size" +" "+ "800,600" + "AnyThingYouWish";
  runProg.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
  //And start your application
  runProg.Start();
```

Comment: Thanks @koviroli

Answer (score 0):

I would probably consider using a WebBrowser control anchored on a form that you then set the size of on load.
Would be a lot easier than trying to launch it in a browser and you would retain more control over what happens, for example you would know when the form is closed and may wish to handle that event whereas you would struggle/have to put in more work to managing that with a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are sure to be dealing with only Chrome, your best bet is to launch the executable directly, using command line parameters.

```
chrome.exe --window-size=800,600 "https://www.google.com"
```

However, in the likely event that the browser is already open, this **won't** resize the exsting browser window. Which is exactly as it should be.

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#window-size